# Blender python, how to import external modules to an addon, "Blender3D python win10toast"

Tags: python, external-applications, library

I'm trying to import external modules in an addon, but I can't find a way to do it.
[image]

In the addon install a "virtual environment" where I have downloaded some modules like win10toast that is used to use windows messages.

[image]

However, I noticed that Blender uses its own "Virtual Environment". I mean Blender has its own python, so I can't import the modules that I have in the virtual environment that is inside the addon, since blender doesn't find those modules because obviously it's not in its virtual environment.
[image]

I read that it is possible to use the "sys" module to tell the compiler where a module is located, however I can't get it to work.

[image]

```
import bpy
import sys

sys.path.append("C:\Users\Ariel\Desktop\Test_message_VScode\venv\Lib\site-packages\win10toast")

from win10toast import ToastNotifier 

for i in sys.path:
    print(i)
    
n = ToastNotifier() 
n.show_toast("GEEKSFORGEEKS", "You got notification", duration = 10)
```

**Someone who can give me an idea of ​​how to import external modules to Blender3D addons?**

I leave attached the folder with a virtual environment of python with the module for windows messages working in VScode.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OR945s227EBbRfbkAqDVi3f8eVWkT_5r/view?usp=sharing

and the blender file where I try to import that module from the external virtual environment.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KjDl0x6usoi16AYWbMCl4QkETNfVxwo7/view?usp=sharing

Thank you so much.